# Objective-C: UILabel Open-End Quote

Tags: objective-c, ios, uilabel

I am going to put a dialogue on my app with UILabel but i don;t know how to put an Open & End quote to it.

How will a able to do it??

Comment: what do you mean by open and end quote?

Comment: this "". sample... henry said "Hello!"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to print a " in your string you will need to escape it

Escaping a `"` is done by adding a `\` before it

```
NSString *string = @"\"Hello\"!";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can include quote in `NSString`. you need to use like -

```
NSString *myString = @"quote: \"";

self.myLabel.text = @"Your text with quotation: \"";
```

Comment: why down vote, explain please?

Comment: I didn't down vote, but I think it ought to be mandatory to leave a comment explaining a down vote when you do it.

Comment: @ElJay - correct, and that comment also inform me if i have done something wrong.